# TypeError: Cursor.callproc() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Tags: python, mysql

I need to take 2 dates to call a stored procedure in MySQL from Python, but I get an error

```py
mysql = pymysql.connect(
    host='localhost',
    user='root',
    password='',
    db='fact',
    charset='utf8mb4',
    cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
) 
cur = mysql.cursor()  
cur.callproc('CALL Buscar_fecha',form.dt1.data, form.dt2.data)
comitt = cur.fetchall()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to official document: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-callproc.html

You should pass the arguments in a tuple like this:

```
cur.callproc('Buscar_fecha', (form.dt1.data, form.dt2.data))
```

Comment: Now it throws me this error   ProgrammingError

pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Buscar_fecha_0='2023-02-08',@_CALL Buscar_fecha_1='2023-02-03'' at line 1")

Comment: I do not know what you data is. You could try to debug the problem from the simplest example, for example: `cur.callproc('my_test', (1, 2))` , then make it more complex step by step.